# I can't use a Client Plugins to render an element in a Client Only Tags in Nuxt

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt on a project  that has a search input in the header.

I Implemented it using Mabpox Geocoder and it works fine but on first page load the search input appears like this
[image]

When the mounted hook gets executed and the plugin loads the geocoder it looks fine
[image]

I wanted to use the `<client-only>` tag to put a placeholder until the real search is fetched
But I get this error:

> 500 can't access property "querySelector", geocoderContainer is null

`Search.vue`:

```html
<template>
  <div> 
    <client-only>
      <div :id="geocoderID" @resultFound="resultFound"></div>
    </client-only>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    geocoderID() {
      return `mapbox-geocoder-${this.containerID}`;
    },
  },

  mounted() {
    this.$mapboxMaps.createGeocoder(this.geocoderID);
  },
}
</script>
```

My `Mapbox.client.js` plugin:

```js
import "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.css";
const mapboxgl = require("mapbox-gl");
import MapboxGeocoder from "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder";
import "@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder/dist/mapbox-gl-geocoder.css";

export default function (context, inject) {
  inject("mapboxMaps", { createGeocoder });
  mapboxgl.accessToken = <my-access-token>

  function createGeocoder(containerID) {
    // Only add the search box if there's none (avoid duplications of boxes)
    const geocoderContainer = document.getElementById(containerID);
    if (geocoderContainer.querySelector(".mapboxgl-ctrl-geocoder")) return;

    const geocoder = new MapboxGeocoder({
      accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
      enableEventLogging: false,
      mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
    });

    geocoder.addTo(geocoderContainer);
  }
```

When I try to log the div to which i want to attach the search using the following

```js
mounted() {
    console.log(this.geocoderID);
    console.log(document.getElementById(this.geocoderID))
    this.$mapboxMaps.createGeocoder(this.geocoderID);
  },
```

It logs this

> mapbox-geocoder-nav-search

> undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/nuxt-components/#the-client-only-component)
[image]

This is what I did

```
methods: {
  renderSearch(count = 10) {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      if (document.getElementById(this.geocoderID)) {
        this.$mapboxMaps.createGeocoder(this.geocoderID);
      } else if (count > 0) {
        this.initClientOnlyComp(count - 1);
      }
    });
  },
},

mounted() {
  this.renderSearch();
},
```

It worked fine, I logged the count just for curiousity and the element was rendered at `count = 9`.

Comment: I would recommend still using template refs tho, rather than a query selector.

Comment: @kissu you're absloutely right I do use refs but this is a learning project and i was trying to fix the problem.